# Generar PDF CON SSRD

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssrs, reporting

Mi duda es que he generado un grupo de 40 rows  pero  el tablix sige generando solamente 14 ,  lo que deseo es que el detalle se muestre sin repetir la cabecera

Lo que deseo hace  es que la imagen 2 ya no salga sino que el detalle se muestre en la imagen 1 o 3

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

[image: Img3]

Comment: y que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: No te entiendo :/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo q deseas hacer es q los datos del cliente y el cuadro q dice factura electrónica no se repita, y que el cuadro de totales se muestre hasta la ultima pag. si es así, lo que debes hacer es dentro del cuerpo del reporte agregar lo que has puesto en el encabezado, luego la tabla del detalle, seguido de los totales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esa forma el encabezado solo te apareceria en la primer pag y el total al final, independiente del número de pag. que tenga el reporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]